# making an array within an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, matplotlib, vector

I am trying to make in python an array within an array that looks like this:

```
[[3,0,-3,-4],[6,0,-2.44,-4]]
```

which I could use in a vector plot in matplotlib.

I tried doing this with the following program:

```
data = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1], dtype='str',delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7))

x = data[:,0].astype(float)
u = data[:,6].astype(float)
v = data[:,7].astype(float)

soa = []
for t in range(0,2):
    print "At time ",x[t]," U is ",u[t]," and V is ",v[t]
    result = [x[t],0,u[t],v[t]] 
    soa = np.append(soa, [result])


print "soa is ",soa
```

When I run the program I get the output:

soa is  [ 3.          0.         -3. -4.          6.          0.
 -2.44 -4.        ]

This cannot be plotted as a vector plot in matplotlib.  How can I tweak the above script to get the array into the format:

```
 [[3,0,-3,-4],[6,0,-2.44,-4]]
```

where [3,0,-3,-4] and [6,0,-2.44,-4] are vectors that I could plot in matplotlib?

Comment: quick fix, `soa = soa.reshape((2,-1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

np.append is different than the noraml array append.

try:

```
for t in range(0,2):
    print "At time ",x[t]," U is ",u[t]," and V is ",v[t]
    result = [x[t],0,u[t],v[t]] 
    soa.append(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get the desired array is to simply stack the columns from the data and put a zero column in the middle

```
data = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1], dtype='str',delimiter=',', skiprows=1, 
                  usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7))

x = data[:,0].astype(float)
u = data[:,6].astype(float)
v = data[:,7].astype(float)

soa = np.vstack((x,np.zeros(len(x)),u,v)).T

print "soa is ",soa
```